# What's the correct way to redirect to a different relative URL path in AngularJS? (i.e. change URL - with maybe $location.path - and then refresh)

Tags: angularjs

Suppose this is my HTML (which gets served when accessing the path `/`:

```
<form ng-submit="ctrl.loginUser()" name="myLoginForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="uname" class="form-control" ng-model="ctrl.loginuser.username" required> 
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="pwd" class="form-control" ng-model="ctrl.loginuser.password" required>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Login"> 
</form>
```

This is the HTML page which shows up when I access `/home` (`mainPage.html`):

```
<h5>TESTTT</h5>
```

And this is what gets called when the form is submitted:

```
angular.module("BaseApp", [])
    .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
    }])

    .config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider){
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }])

self.loginUser = function(loginuser) {
    return $http.post("/custom-api-auth/login", loginuser)
    .then(function(response) {
        $location.url("/home");
    });
};
```

I tried testing this and submitting the form. The URL does change to `/home` but the page which gets served when going to the URL `www.url.com/home` does not appear. The page does not refresh either.

As mentioned earlier, wen I go to `www.url.com/home`, `mainPage.html` does in fact show up.

What steps do I take to have it so that it correct redirects to the `/home` URL?

Comment: Do you have routing configured?

Comment: @user2719875: Please add routing config also

Comment: @Phil I edited my post to add more information. As mentioned in the title, I want to refresh the page and load an entirely new template, so I don't have routing configured in AngularJS. My backend is Python / Django, which serves a template when accessing the URL `/home`. The template the backend serves when accessing the `/home` URL is what I want to appear when `$location.url("/home")` is executed.

Comment: @MuhammedNeswine I edited my post to add more information. As mentioned in the title, I want to refresh the page and load an entirely new template, so I don't have routing configured in AngularJS. My backend is Python / Django, which serves a template when accessing the URL `/home`. The template the backend serves when accessing the `/home` URL is what I want to appear when `$location.url("/home")` is executed.

Comment: Ah, you should probably use `$window.location.href = '/home'` instead. Angular's `$location` service is for dealing with in-app URL manipulation

Comment: @Phil Hm okay, I'll look into that. Also, feel free to look at this question I just asked (which also uses `ngroute`): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43196487/angularjs-router-does-not-load-page-served-at-templateurl

Answer (score 0):

The way I would to use ui-router you can read more here.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

You can use resolve to provide your controller with content or data that is custom to the state. In this case if you want to go to test, but previously you need to fullfill a promise this would be an example.

```
$stateProvider.state('test', {
  resolve:{

     // Example using function with simple return value.
     // Since it's not a promise, it resolves immediately.
     simpleObj:  function(){
        return {value: 'simple!'};
     },

     // Example using function with returned promise.
     // This is the typical use case of resolve.
     // You need to inject any services that you are
     // using, e.g. $http in this example
     promiseObj:  function($http){
        // $http returns a promise for the url data
        return $http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'});
     },



  },
```